# Basic set notation - Concept Clarification

Tags: functions

Why is the set notation  {3,6} ∈ Z false ?

Is it because {3,6} represents a set but not two individual element?

Comment: Because $\{3,6\}$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 3):

It should be $\{3,6\}\subset\mathbb{Z}$, since $3$, $4$ are members of $\Bbb{Z}$. On the other hand, $\{3,6\}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., $\{3,6\}$ is not an integer, is a set of two integers).